# vim color changing between | |

Tags: vim, vimrc, vi-mode

I'm editing some rst files. In the math section, the color changes between | |. Why is this so? How can I change my rst.vim file to not change color between | |?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out which syntax group causes the highlighting. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin. When you have the name of the offending syntax group, you can link it to another highlighting group in your `~/.vimrc`, like this:

```
:highlight link rstGroupName Normal
```